# Can't launch server QWsServer error : The address is protected

Tags: android, c++, qt, websocket

I'm trying to do a C++ websocket server. I want to "speak" to an android Application and send it videos.

I'm using QtWebsocket from [this repository](https://gitorious.org/qtwebsocket/cmoh-qtwebsocket/source/3965b7b5741509d2e6589e72fb67beeda3f72b2b)

To test, I copied the code from Example/Server.
I haven't had any compilation error but the server cannot start:

> Error: Can't launch server QWsServer error : The address is protected

I am beginner in network and websockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port you are trying to listen on -> **80** is available only to privileged applications (and only if no other process is listening on it). Try using different port (ex. 8080), or running your application as *root*.

For more info about ports check out: [Privileged Ports](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)

Comment: This worked, I had to put the port 8082 becaus I had tomcat servers running !